# 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash-cs4, movieclip

I've been using Adobe Flash CS4 for a couple of days.  I've drawn a worm, with eyes and a mouth and these pieces are all MovieClip symbols.  I have exported them to actionscript with the class name being the same as what they are (ie. the mouth MovieClip is exported as mouth).  The mouth has 2 frames, one smiling and one frowning.  I need to mouth to stay smiling at first, so in Frame 1 actions I wrote:

```
mouth.gotoAndStop(1);
```

But I get this compiler error:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type Class.
```

Why is this occuring? Thanks.

Comment: It depends where you placed your code. If you paced it inside the mouth symbol, simply calling gotoAndStop(1) or stop() should do the trick.

Comment: It worked, I knew it would be something really obvious.  Is that the only way I can access the MovieClip in AS3 or can I access it through the main timeline's actions somehow?  I got this working a long time ago when I had the trial of Flash I think, but I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your Movieclip an instance name in order to reference it by code (if you don´t use stop() inside the mouth clip). Select your Movieclip and give it an instance name in the properties window. If you have nested your mouth instance and want to control it from the main timeline/class you should also declare the full body of the snake.

```
snake.mouth.gotoAndStop(1);
```

[image]

Comment: If I give it an instance name in the properties window like you said, I still get a compilation error, 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mouth.  It's probably me being newbish again.  Thanks for your answer, but it's worm not a snake ;)  EDIT: Actually, it works when I write Mouth instead of mouth like @Theo said.  Thanks, both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that `mouth` is a class. I assume you've named both the class (symbol) and the instance "mouth". Try renaming the class (symbol) to something else, like `Mouth` (the convention is to use an uppercase initial for class names).